# placement of blocprovider for cbuit

Tags: flutter, cubit

New at flutter and cubit ...  so ....

my test app shows    +  0  -    widgets and i can get the cubit to increment and decrement this ok.

but i am try to place this cubit code within my real app.  which is building a listview of bagel names from a json file. The I tring to place the counter widget into my app.  it builds a list view from a json fiel with 15 bagel names  I had this app working with a state change and trying to move to cubit.

the problem is I not sure where to insert the provder code.  nothing i seem to try works[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYigB.png)

```
  home: CubitProvider(
        create: (_) => CounterCubit(),
        child: CounterPage(),
```

in to working app.

main.dart
counter_cubit_page.dart

Comment: i found my answer in my better understanding of flutter widget tree after watching this video   tutorial on bloc/cubit..   https://youtu.be/THCkkQ-V1-8

Answer (score 0):

There is no CubitProvider class in flutter_bloc. it should be BlocProvider

```
home: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => CounterCubit(),
        child: CounterPage(),
```

Comment: thanks i did have BlockProvider.   i was thinking cubit..  when i typed code out on above comments